# Changing colours and fonts in WebStorm 2016.1

Tags: macos, webstorm

I have just downloaded WebStorm 2016.1 for Mac OS X. I would like to configure my editor fonts and colorus.

I understand that you must save the scheme before it becomes editable. This I have done:

[image]

but the options still remain unavailable.

Is this a limitation of the trial or something? What have I missed? I have applied the style, and have even closed down WebStorm and re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

If certain style (e.g. "Doc comment" on your screenshot) has `Use inherited attributes` option checked .. then it re-uses colors from parent option (which is displayed just below it).

The solution is simple:

- either edit parent style
- or uncheck that `Use inherited attributes` option and edit your colors here

---

**P.S.**

Trial version has NO limitation in functionality.